# Paging AND Sorting in DataGrid using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm struggling to get paging and sorting (on multiple headers) going on using MVVM in WPF.

I've got paging working using a custom control and sorting also kind of works but not quite.

I can handle the event Sorting event binding a command to it get the SortDescriptions (ICollectionView) do the sorting over the pages. This works with multiple header.

The only thing is, when I don't set handled on DataGridSortingEventArgs the client also sort. That I don't want, but when I set DataGridSortingEventArgs is handled the sort indicator doesn't indicate.....

--- Result ---

1. Implemented custom paging.
2. Use binding on SortDirection for each header in the DataGrid.
3. Handled DataGrid Sorting event (using GalaSoft)

2.1. Set argument to handled

2.2. Set direction on column manually(from args)

2.3. Remove SortDescriptions using the binding from 2 (the ones with no sort direction)

2.5. Insert SortDescription from column on ICollectionView

Presto. It work as I need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cancel the event and set the [SortDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.sortdirection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) "manually"

Comment: Do I only have to set the 'last' SortDirection? when doing multiple header sorting?

Comment: As far as i know you can only set SortDirection on 1 column, but you can sort by how many columns you like